# about login process in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I want to login an admin login GUI page, with this login process i want to open a new related GUI window.I have made a database "MY MINI PROJECT.DB" for this adding username and password as columns and Want to fetch and match data from it. But with my code next window is opening directly without checking the if condition.please help.i am frustrated.Here is my code.

```
def e():
    while True:
        USERNAME = StringVar()
        PASSWORD = StringVar()
        username = USERNAME.get()
        password = PASSWORD.get()
        db = sqlite3.connect('welcome.db')
        cr = db.cursor()
        if (USERNAME== "" and PASSWORD== ""):
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("ALERT","CANNOT BE BLANK")
        elif db:
            cr.execute("select USERNAME AND PASSWORD from ADMIN_LOGIN where USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?"), (username,password))
            result = cr.fetchall()
            if result:
            for i in result:
                print("welcome"+i[2])
                break
            else:
                print("bye")
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("ALERT","NO RECORD FOUND")
                break
db.commit()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've not included a proper [mcve]. You haven't showed us what calls `e()`.

Comment: "next window is opening" which window do you mean?

Comment: sorry for inappropriate information.The function e() is called by the window that has username and password and their entry box. Actually i wanted to create login page and its functioning would perform in this function which is called by the login page function.

Comment: "next window is opening" means the window that opens after logging in that i have made for admin.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in logging in process after understanding the concept deeply.Here is the code.

```
        def admin_login():
            if ADMIN_USERNAME.get() == "" or ADMIN_PASSWORD.get() == "":
                l2.config(text="PLEASE COMPLETE THE REQUIRED FIELD!!", fg="red", bg="yellow", font=f7)
           else:
               c.execute("SELECT * FROM ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE ADMIN_USERNAME = ? AND ADMIN_PASSWORD = ?",
                       (ADMIN_USERNAME.get(), ADMIN_PASSWORD.get()))
               if c.fetchone() is not None:
                   e()
                   ADMIN_USERNAME.set("")
                   ADMIN_PASSWORD.set("")
               else:
                   l2.config(text="INVALID ADMIN USERNAME OR PASSWORD!", fg="red", bg="yellow", font=f7)
                   ADMIN_USERNAME.set("")
                   ADMIN_PASSWORD.set("")
           connn.commit()
```

I have made the function ADMIN_LOGIN() inside the same function that creates the login page.Previously I was trying to make both functions separately.Now it is working smoothly.Thank you.